# Firebase does not work at the first time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to generate a report pdf counting on total Orders and orders with status wanted

I have this code to create pdf and fill table out

```
private TemplatePDF templatePDF;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference reference;

Button btnRatio1;

ArrayList<String[]> rowqa=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reportes);

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=database.getReference("Requests");

    btnRatio1=findViewById(R.id.Quality);

    btnRatio1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reference.orderByChild("date").startAt("1530002755582").endAt("1530504865654").
                    addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            showData(dataSnapshot);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

            createTemplate(rowqa);
        }
    });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    int total=(int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    int count=0;
    String[]row;
    for (DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Request rq = myDataSnapshot.getValue(Request.class);
        if (rq.getStatuscali().equals("0"))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    row= new String[]{Common.getDate(Long.parseLong("1529945980802")),String.valueOf(count),String.valueOf(total),""+ count/total};
    addRow(row);

}
private void createTemplate(ArrayList<String[]> rowqa) {
    TemplatePDF templatePDF1 = new TemplatePDF(getApplicationContext());
    templatePDF1.openDocument("Quality");
    templatePDF1.addTitles("Frutifelles E.I.R.L.","Calidad de pedidos generados","25/06/2018");
    templatePDF1.createTable(header,rowqa);
    templatePDF1.closeDocument();
    templatePDF1.viewPDF();
}

private void addRow(String[]row){
    rowqa.add(row);
}
```

The first time show me my pdf this way

> [image]

But the second time show me correctly

> [image]

It seems like first time it doesn't work

Comment: please include the images in the post rather than posting a link

Comment: @Ibo OP doesn't have enough reputation to post the images.

Comment: Yes, I don't. But I tried and think it worked

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I forgot about it, I thought new members can post images right off the bat

Comment: What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with asynchronous programming. You're calling `createTemplate(rowqa)` outside of the onDataChange function, so it will be triggered before data is present. [This article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) might help a bit.

Comment: Yes, when I put it inside it works, but I get a row by Firebase query and I want to repeat the query for every day of the month, implementing a method and passing the dates as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

just as @Jen Person said, you should put the `createTemplate(rowqa)` inside the `onDataChange` callback, else when you click the button at the first time, the `rowqa` is empty, so `createTemplate(rowqa)` will get an empty PDF.

an example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reportes);

    btnRatio1=findViewById(R.id.Quality);
    btnRatio1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // dateStart, dateEnd should be instance fields
          queryData(dateStart, dateEnd);
        }
    });
}

private void queryData(String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=database.getReference("Requests");
    reference.orderByChild("date")
            .startAt(dateStart)
            .endAt(dateEnd)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    showData(dataSnapshot);
                    createTemplate(rowqa);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but now I have to repeat the query according to the number of days I choose. Therefore, first I have to load the matrix and at the end createTemplate (rowqa), I worked with 2 buttons, the first button loads Array while waiting for the asynchronous and another for createTemplate, interestingly, the ValueEventListeners do not really capture their data in the order in which they are encoded, so I receive a messy report.